# Install PyTorch from requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, requirements.txt

Torch documentation says use

```
pip install torch==1.4.0+cpu torchvision==0.5.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

to install the latest version of PyTorch. This works when I do it manually but when I add it to req.txt and do `pip install -r req.txt`, it fails and says  `ERROR: No matching distribution`.

Edit: adding the whole line from req.txt and error here.

```
torch==1.4.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

torchvision==0.5.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.htmltorch==1.4.0+cpu
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.4.0+cpu (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1.post2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.4.0+cpu (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: @NilankaManoj python version: 3.6.9

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Add `--find-links` in `requirements.txt` before torch

```
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

torch==1.2.0+cpu
```

Source: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/29745#issuecomment-553588171

Comment: Not sure if something changed, but I was able to install the latest version by adding `torch` and  `torchvision` on separate lines to `requirements.txt`. Or `torch>=2.0.1` for that version or higher. No `--find-links` required.

Answer (score 16):

To get the cuda version that I needed (instead of whatever the repos serve up), I converted the cuda-specific installation command from [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/):

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

into this at the top of requirements.txt:

```
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
torch
torchvision
torchaudio
```

Then I do the usual `pip install -r requirements.txt` and when I `import torch` and run `torch.version.cuda` inside python, I get '11.6' as I wanted.

Comment: This also works with the cpu only version.  The link would be `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu`.  The accepted answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 13):

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html 
torch==1.4.0+cpu 
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torchvision==0.5.0+cpu
```

worked fine for me :)

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like that:

$ `pip install -r req.txt --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Just put your PyTorch requirements in `req.txt` like this:

`torch==1.4.0+cpu`

`torchvision==0.5.0+cpu`

Comment: It's possible the OP can't use any other command except `pip install -r req.txt`. I have the same issue; `pip install -r requirements.txt` is run by another team, not me; all I have control over is the contents of requirements.txt.

Comment: For some reason, the version ```torch==1.2.0+cpu``` in the accepted answer doesn't work for me, but this one does.

Answer (score 4):

For me, this `requirement.txt` worked for CPU version installation

```
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
torch
torchvision
```