# requirements.txt pytorch with ">=" greater than?

Tags: pip, pytorch, requirements.txt

I have a requirements.txt from a Github repo that contains following lines:

```
torch>=1.7.0,!=1.12.0
torchvision>=0.8.1,!=0.13.0
// and more
```

As I search SO and google they say I need to install pytorch with cuda specified, e.g. `+cu110`; in order to enable GPU and use the installed cuda.

So, for example this command does work on CLI: `pip install torch==1.7.1+cu110 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

But the problem is with requirements.txt.

I looked [Install PyTorch from requirements.txt - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912744/install-pytorch-from-requirements-txt) and tried some solutions but they didn't work as the following.

```
// simply added `+cu110`
// didn't work
torch>=1.7.0+cu110,!=1.12.0
torchvision>=0.8.1+cu110,!=0.13.0
```

```
// w/ --extra-index-url
// didn't work
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu110
torch>=1.7.0+cu110,!=1.12.0
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu110
torchvision>=0.8.1+cu110,!=0.13.0
```

```
// w/ -f
// didn't work
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch>=1.7.0+cu110,!=1.12.0
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torchvision>=0.8.1+cu110,!=0.13.0
```

So, is it possible to work with the combination of `>=` and `+cu110` in requirements.txt?

### Edit

It still doesn't work with no `+cu110`.

The following doesn't install cuda, but instead installs a normal torch.

```
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu110
torch>=1.7.0+cu110,!=1.12.0
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu110
torchvision>=0.8.1+cu110,!=0.13.0
```

So the stdout result is like:

```
Collecting torch!=1.12.0,>=1.7.0
  Using cached torch-1.13.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (167.3 MB)
```

And `pip freeze` shows:

```
torch==1.13.0
torchvision==0.14.0
```

The following also doesn't install cuda.

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu110
torch>=1.7.0,!=1.12.0
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu110
torchvision>=0.8.1,!=0.13.0
```

The stdout and `pip freeze` result is the same to the above.

The following also doesn't work, it installs cuda, but it installs a random version of cuda. (it's understandable because I didn't specify a version I prefer)

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch>=1.7.0,!=1.12.0
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torchvision>=0.8.1,!=0.13.0
```

The stdout:

```
Collecting torch!=1.12.0,>=1.7.0
  Using cached https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117/torch-1.13.0%2Bcu117-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (2258.1 MB)
Collecting torchvision!=0.13.0,>=0.8.1
  Using cached https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117/torchvision-0.14.0%2Bcu117-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (4.8 MB)
```

`pip freeze` result:

```
torch==1.13.0+cu117
torchvision==0.14.0+cu117
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the `+cu110`. It does not seem to be valid notation to me anyway.

Comment: I added the edit section. Please take a look. Thanks.