# How do I install Triton with pip in docker?

Tags: docker-compose, pip

For my project I need to create a docker container to run my PyTorch project. I need to install the pip dependecies in order for it to run. I placed these dependencies in the requirements.txt

requirements.txt

```
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==2.1.2+cu121
torchvision
```

When running the container via `docker-compose up` it crashed following this error:

terminal

```
User@Machine:~/Documents/my-app$ docker-compose up
Building app
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  214.5kB
Step 1/12 : FROM python:3.10-alpine
 ---> 5fee4875cce7
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 18a73e195c41
Step 3/12 : ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7f968d5a4a5b
Step 4/12 : ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 238a69a9bf55
Step 5/12 : ENV FLASK_ENV=development
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b2bc590c36c5
Step 6/12 : RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1de406a6a320
Step 7/12 : COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 402b0ab57de2
Step 8/12 : RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5caef648e971
Step 9/12 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in d586ecebf890
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement triton==2.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for triton==2.1.0
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

I got the same type of error for the pytorch dependency, but this ([Install PyTorch from requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912744/install-pytorch-from-requirements-txt)) post fixed that. I have tried the to find a similar solution for triton, but I couldn't find it.

With Triton manually added to the requirements the same kind of error gets displayed.
requirements.txt

```
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==2.1.2+cu121
torchvision
triton==2.1.0
```

terminal

```
User@Machine:~/Documents/my-app$ docker-compose up
Building app
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  214.5kB
Step 1/12 : FROM python:3.10-alpine
 ---> 5fee4875cce7
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 18a73e195c41
Step 3/12 : ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7f968d5a4a5b
Step 4/12 : ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 238a69a9bf55
Step 5/12 : ENV FLASK_ENV=development
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b2bc590c36c5
Step 6/12 : RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1de406a6a320
Step 7/12 : COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> e510cb626e2f
Step 8/12 : RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in 421ff643582b
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (23.0.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-23.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 24.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 23.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-23.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-23.0.1
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Successfully installed pip-23.3.2
Removing intermediate container 421ff643582b
 ---> f0d4389ab959
Step 9/12 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in cfbc6e038af6
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html, https://pypi.org/project/triton/#files
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement triton==2.2.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for triton==2.2.0
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
(base) luke@Luke-AI:~/Documents/my-flask-app$ docker-compose up
Building app
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  214.5kB
Step 1/12 : FROM python:3.10-alpine
 ---> 5fee4875cce7
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 18a73e195c41
Step 3/12 : ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7f968d5a4a5b
Step 4/12 : ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 238a69a9bf55
Step 5/12 : ENV FLASK_ENV=development
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b2bc590c36c5
Step 6/12 : RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1de406a6a320
Step 7/12 : COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> 40c4ef63e751
Step 8/12 : RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in 1c738fba1924
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (23.0.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-23.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 18.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 23.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-23.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-23.0.1
Successfully installed pip-23.3.2
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Removing intermediate container 1c738fba1924
 ---> 6f47088b7f07
Step 9/12 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 323379cf3067
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Collecting torch==2.1.2+cu121 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/torch-2.1.2%2Bcu121-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl (2200.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.2/2.2 GB 6.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting torchvision (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/rocm5.6/torchvision-0.16.2%2Brocm5.6-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl (65.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 65.1/65.1 MB 40.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement triton==2.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for triton==2.1.0
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: Build failed
```

And with only Triton in the requirements, I again get the same kind of error:

requirements.txt

```
triton==2.1.0
```

terminal

```
User@Machine:~/Documents/my-app$ docker-compose up
Building app
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  214.5kB
Step 1/12 : FROM python:3.10-alpine
 ---> 5fee4875cce7
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 18a73e195c41
Step 3/12 : ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7f968d5a4a5b
Step 4/12 : ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 238a69a9bf55
Step 5/12 : ENV FLASK_ENV=development
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b2bc590c36c5
Step 6/12 : RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1de406a6a320
Step 7/12 : COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
 ---> fb2e598a7303
Step 8/12 : RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in 1266ffa95041
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (23.0.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-23.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 15.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 23.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-23.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-23.0.1
Successfully installed pip-23.3.2
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Removing intermediate container 1266ffa95041
 ---> b4691d6f0c1c
Step 9/12 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in df6716539302
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement triton==2.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for triton==2.1.0
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

Below you can find my Dockerfile and compose.yaml, these are almost completely similar to the tutorial about docker compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted), which I was able to run on my machine:

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.10-alpine

WORKDIR /code

ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_ENV=development

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=app.py
      - FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - FLASK_ENV=development
    command: flask run
```

Finally the app.py it is trying to run, some code left out it runs without docker:

```
import torch
from nst import NST
from time import sleep
from torch import Tensor
from functools import wraps 
from flask import Flask, request, abort 

import threading
import uuid
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
queue = StyleTransferQueue(maxsize=10)

API_KEYS = {

}

thread_event = threading.Event()

def require_apikey(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
 
@app.route("/enqueue", methods=["POST"])
@require_apikey  # Protects this endpoint with the API key check
def enqueue():


@app.route("/poll", methods=["GET"])
@require_apikey  # Protects this endpoint with the API key check
def poll():
```

Comment: `triton==2.1.0` is not in your `requirements.txt`, where it came from? AFAIU `triton` should be installed from PyPI. I suspect `--find-links` override `pip`'s search algorithm so it no longer looks up packages at PyPI. Split your `requirements.txt` into two — one with `--find-links` and `torch`-related packages, one with dependencies coming from PyPI.